# Is it possible for me to open a new tab while redirect current page to another form?

Tags: button, model-view-controller, backend

I know there is code which allow us to open a new tab when click the button (either in javascript/controller) .But I wish to know is there a way for me to open a new tab meanwhile redirect my current page to another page in just a button click. Right now I only able to open a new tab when click the button.
Controller code is preferred.

twig file

```
<button type="submit" id="button-receipt" form="form-layout" formaction="{{ receipt }}" formtarget="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_receipt_print }}" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></button>
```

controller file

```
$data['receipt'] = $this->url->link('sale/salesorder/receipt', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'], true);

receipt{
  $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('sale/salesorder_receipt', $data));
}
```

Anyone can help on this? Thanks.

Comment: "`formtarget="_blank"`" does **not** require the target to be opened in "a new tab" - only a new window, which _may or may not_ be in a new browser tab - that depends entirely on the user's browser settings, and JavaScript cannot override that at all.

Comment: i am using this code and try in chrome. by adding formtarget="_blank", once the button is clicked, chrome will open a new tab and go to the link(which is what i want). Just i am unable to redirect current page to another link at same time :(

Comment: You can't do that in a HTTP response.